# Does tomcat compile servlets automatically?

Tags: tomcat, deployment

When we modify a JSP , we can just overwrite the jsp and tomcat autmatically recompile the servelt asociated to it ,
 but if we want to modify a servlet is enough to modify the .java or we need to deploy the .class too?  ( I mean is tomcat capable of compiling  the .java into a .class if a .clss is not found or is outdated)
   The question  is if just deploying  the .java from svn to the server and restarting tomcat imply that tomcat compile the .java in a .class or we need to deploy the .class too ( and having it in svn too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tomcat deploy documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) says that if you use the Tomcat Client Deployer, it will automatically compile .java files located under /WEB-INF/classes. So if you put your sources there, they will be auto-compiled.